# That is abstract but has non virtual destructor The delete is causing an error. Why is that?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
 virtual void cry() = 0;
 void eat();
};


class Cat:public Animal
{
public:
        virtual void cry();
        void grooming();
};


class Dog:public Animal
{
public:
        virtual void cry();
        void lash();
};


main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Cat();
    animal->eat();
    animal->cry();

    Cat* cat = (Cat*)animal;
    cat->grooming();

    Dog* dog = new Dog();
    dog->cry();
    dog->eat();
    dog->lash();

    delete animal;     //Delete called on'animal' that is abstract but has non-virtual destruct
    delete cat;             //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    delete dog;
}
```

The delete is causing an error. Why is that?
Attempt to release memory via delete without using destructors, but an error occurs
"Delete called on'animal' that is abstract but has non-virtual destruct
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: If one of the given answers answers your question to your satisfaction, you could accept the answer.

Comment: There are two causes of undefined behaviour. First, `delete animal` has undefined behaviour - according to the C++ standard - due to `animal` being a pointer to a base class that points at an instance of a derived class.   The only fix is to give `Animal` a `virtual` destructor.  Second (even if the first problem is fixed) `delete cat` attempts to `delete` an object that has already been deleted - which gives undefined behaviour due to `delete`ing an object more than once.    The fix for that is to `delete animal` (which requires the virtual destructor) OR to `delete cat` but NOT to do both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is telling you what the issue is. You are destroying your virtual objects with a non-virtual destructor.

You have `virtual void cry` why? Its so that when you call `animal->cry`, it calls the `Cat` cry, not the default `Animal` cry. The same is true of the virtual destructor. When you call `delete animal` you need it to call the destructor of the actual object, not just the base class. You need to add:

```
virtual ~Animal() = default;
```

to your animal class.

> A **base** class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and non-virtual

[Cpp Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-non-virtual)

As for the second issue, the double delete:

```
delete animal; // deletes the object
delete cat; // deletes the same object again, because cat and animal point to 
            // the same place.
```

Some suggest to not delete twice, i would suggest to not call delete explicitly at all. Use a smart pointer:

```
auto animal = std::make_unique<Cat>();
Cat &cat = *animal;

animal->cry();
cat.cry(); // Calls the same function as above.
```

Unique pointer will handle the deletion of the object for you.

Comment: `delete cat;` will also fail as `cat` is a casted copy of `animal`, not a `new`ed object.

Comment: @KenY-N  Untrue.   `animal` points at a "`new`ed object" that is actually of type `Cat`, so the casting `Animal *` to `Cat *` is not a cause of any problem.  The problem is, in addition to what this answer says, that the object is being destroyed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete the same object twice:

```
Animal* animal = new Cat();

Cat* cat = (Cat*)animal;   // cat points to the same object as animal
...
delete animal;     // first delete
delete cat;        // second attemp fails
```

Comment: The first delete is also wrong in the code. Because of no virtual destructor.